# Add to a List where some elements are already present

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that already has some elements present before attempting to add more. I retrieve the machine name and type, and then use the machine name to gather information on the machine.

Here is my object:

```
    public string HostName;
    public string machinetype;
    public string osVersion;
    public ulong cDriveFreeSpace;
    public string sqlVersion;
    public string ieVersion;
    public string adobeVersion;
    public ulong totalRAM;
    public string ProcessorDescription;
    public string PhysicalProcessors;
    public string LogicalCoreProcessors;
    public ulong MemorySize;
    public List<SystemTools.LogicalDriveInfo> Drives = new List<SystemTools.LogicalDriveInfo>();
    public string OSArchitecture;
    public string DotNetVersion;
```

First I gather the HostName and machinetype:

```
List<Machines> result = new List<Machines>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    result.Add(new Machines((dr.IsNull("HostName") ? "" : dr["HostName"]).ToString(), dr["machinetype"].ToString()));
                }
                return result;
```

What I want is for each machine name to go out and retrieve the information I have listed. I've already got methods to do that, but I've confused myself as to how to add these elements to the list in the proper way.

I was thinking something like below. I want to avoid create a new Machine type as this would erase the hostname and machinetype

```
    for (int i = 0; i < machineList.Count; i++)
    {
       machineList.insert(i, ????) //do this for each element I want to add.
    }
```

As an added bonus if anyone can provide an example of using a nested list, as I will need to implement  List Drives as well, as machines have multiple drives. Any help is appreciated as im a bit stuck, thanks.

Comment: Adding new elements to a list doesn't remove existing ones. So I don't see what the problem here is. If you want to elaborate, then please go back and fix your code example so that it makes sense. Post a minimal example of the Machine class, with the full declaration (not all those other properties that don't have to do with the question), and explain what "machineList" is and what you're really trying to do with it after you've retrieved the data for your Machine items from the DB.

Comment: I need to use the machine names to search the domain and add the machine information to my List<Machines> machinelist. 

So, for example, the database returns two machines. We have user-pc1 and user-pc2 both with the same type. The objective is to go out and retrieve information from both pcs on the domain and add that to the list. So the initial object will be:

HostName: user-pc1
machineType: Something
osVersion: ?????
ieVersion: ?????

so I would need to insert osVersion, ieVersion, etc at the specified index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to edit the objects in the existing list, not add more objects.

```
foreach (var machine in machineList)
{
    machine.osVersion = "....";
}
```

If you have need to use the index for some reason, then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < machineList.Count; i++)
{
    var machine = machineList[i];
    machine.osVersion = "....";
}
```